# Firebase and Swift 3 Asynchronous Unit Testing

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

So I've done some research online and the best answers I've found are either outdated or intended for Android. Any help is appreciated!

For another project I did within the last week, I had to write about 2 dozen test cases for a custom Heroku/PostGreSQL backend with Swift 2.3. All I did was create an asyncExpectation variable at the beginning of the test, fulfill the expectation after the completion handler executed, and then wait for it to be fulfilled at the bottom of the test.

Now I'm using Firebase and Swift 3 for a new project. For some reason, nothing gets added to the database when I uncomment the `asyncExpectation.fulfill()` below. With it commented out, everything works fine. How should I go about testing data storage/retrieval with Firebase and Swift 3?

Edit: I should include that amidst my researching online, I uncovered that I may need to use dispatching, but this seems like a solution for nested completionHandlers, whereas my database `append` method isn't quite a completionHandler, so I'm at a loss for how to proceed.

```
class RooMate_v2Tests: XCTestCase {
    func testCreateUser() {

        let asyncExpectation = expectation(description: "createUserTestOne")
        var testSuccess = false

        let testUser = (email: "TESTUSER|" + String().randomString(length: 6) + "@test.com", password: String().randomString(length: 6), firstName: "jimmy", lastName: "jenkins")

        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: testUser.email, password: testUser.password) { (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
            print("Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
            } else {
            let userProfileInfo = ["firstName" : testUser.firstName,
                                   "lastName" : testUser.lastName,
                                   "email" : testUser.email,
                                   "profilePictureURL" : "N/A"]

                let backendRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()                
                backendRef.child("users").child("TESTUSER|" + user!.uid).setValue(userProfileInfo)
                // testSuccess = true
            }
            // asyncExpectation.fulfill()
        }

        waitForExpectations(timeout: 10) { (error) in
            XCTAssertTrue(testSuccess)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set a higher timeout?

Comment: Yes I have tried that. The timeout doesn't appear to be the issue. That's a good suggestion though, because this would explain why deleting the expectation.fulfill() makes it work. I've made it 30 seconds and it still won't work. When I delete the fulfillment, it only takes ~5 seconds to add data to backend.

Comment: Have you taken a look at my answer? Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, your problem is that you are checking the success of the setValue in the handler of the wait. As described in the documentation, **the handler is called only in case of time out**:

> A block to be invoked when a call to
>   -waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:handler: times out or has had all associated expectations fulfilled.

I suggest you to retrieve the value just set and check it, something like this:

```
let retrievedUserProfile = backendRef.child("users").child("TESTUSER|" + user!.uid)
XCTAssertTrue(retrievedUserProfile == userProfileInfo)
```

I don't know if this code is correct, it is just to explain my suggestion.
I hope it's helpful!